# How to center head result in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to create a `.pdf` using R Markdown. I want to print some of the first elements of a data frame. I want them to be centered in the page, but i could not obtain that. The R-Markdown code is:

````
The data now looks as follows:

```{r echo = FALSE}
head(x = sample_data, n = 10)
```
````

I have tried with the `results='asis'` parameter in the R fragment but it just sets all the data in the same line as:

```
##        Sample Distr## 1   0.4789297    v1## 2  -2.0690630    v1## 3   0.3468683    v1## 4   0.5035847    v1## 5   1.8031489    v1## 6  -0.5564003    v1## 7  -0.5337388    v1## 8  -0.1199640    v1## 9  -0.1003587    v1## 10  1.0479618    v15
```

How can I make it look as a centered table? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try `knitr::kable(head(sample_data))` for a simple table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `kable()` from package **knitr** is pretty useful for simple tables, and they are centered by default for PDF output.

For your example you could put

```
knitr::kable(head(sample_data))
```

in the chunk.  If you loaded **knitr** earlier in your document you won't need to specifically reference the package like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [`stargazer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf) with the cell set to `results='asis'`.
By default it formats your input as LaTeX which should be processed depending on which `.pdf` converter you're using; another option is to output the `.rmd` as html (`type='html'`), you can then add css to the top of your `.rmd` file to style the table, then print the webpage as a `.pdf`.